# Delete armature and bake animation / boolean

Tags: animation, scripting, modifiers, armature

I have an object parented to an armature that is animated with a series of movements. I need to perform some boolean operations to this object in different frames of the animation, but if I just add a boolean modifier below the armature and apply it, I get incorrect results. I think that baking the animation to the object will be the solution since I can get rid of the armature modifier. But I have searched all the internet and couldn't find a method or a script for this.

The middle hole was a test without animation and everything works perfect, the object I'm trying to cut is the yellow cone. In the second picture, you can see the result after adding the boolean modifier. And the third one shows the result after applying the modifier.

I can not apply the armature modifier or I will lose the original position of my model. (If I apply armature first it works)

[image: Scene]
[image: Boolean modifier]
[image: Result after apply]

Comment: What do you mean incorrect results? As far as I know there is no such kind of baking the animation to the object.

Comment: Boolean should not be malfunctioning with the animation, and you might actually run into more trouble trying to find an alternative. Can you post screenshots of what exactly is happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I figured out how to work around this. Instead of using the armature modifier, I set my armature as a constrain. Then when I perform the boolean everything works as intended. I'm pretty sure it has to do with the hierarchy in the modifiers panel.

Anyway, I'm happy it's working now and that was the solution in case someone else is having trouble with it.